# JQuery form validate only input type = text or type = password

Tags: jquery, forms, validation

I am creating a form validation script and I have check box's on a couple forms. How can I skip these and only make my form validation check the input fields?

Here is my example.

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/loose.dtd">
<html>
<head>
<title></title>
<meta HTTP-EQUIV="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8">
<META HTTP-EQUIV="Content-Language" CONTENT="en-us">
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.7.min.js"></script>
<script>
$(function() {
    var form_default_texts = [];
    form_defaults = function(){
        $("form :input").filter("[type='text']").each(function() {
            if($(this).val()){
                form_default_texts[$(this).name]=$(this).val();
                $(this).blur(function(){
                    if(!$(this).val()){
                        $(this).val(form_default_texts[$(this).name]).css({color:"#EFEFEF"});
                    }
                }).focus(function(){
                    $(this).val('').css({color:'#191919'});
                }).css({color:'#EFEFEF'});
            }
        });
    };
    form_validate = function(form) {    
        var submit = true;
        $(form.elements).filter("[type='text'], [type='password']").each(function() {
            var field = $(this);
            if(form_default_texts[field.name] == field.val()){
                field.focus();
                submit=false;
            }else{
                switch(field.attr('name')){
                case '': case 'submit':
                    //do nothing.
                    break;
                case 'email':
                    form_clear(field);
                    if(valid_email(field.val()) == false){
                        form_error(field);
                        if(submit){field.focus();}
                        submit = false;
                    }
                    break;
                default:
                    form_clear(field);
                    if(field.val() == ''){
                        form_error(field);
                        if(submit){field.focus();}
                        submit = false;
                    }
                };
            }
        });

        return submit;
    };
    valid_email = function(val){
        var filter = /^[a-zA-Z0-9]+[a-zA-Z0-9_.-]+[a-zA-Z0-9_-]+@[a-zA-Z0-9]+[a-zA-Z0-9.-]+[a-zA-Z0-9]+.[a-z]{2,4}$/;
        if(filter.test(val)){
            return true;
        }else{
            return false;
        }
    };
    form_clear = function(field){
        field.css({background:'#FFFEFB','border-color':'#fafaee'}).next(".error").remove();
    }
    form_error = function(field){
        var form_errors = {fullname:'How do you want to be addressed?',subj:'What is this about?',msg:'What is your message?',email:'Check your email address.',search:'blah blah',q:'testing'};
        var form_error = form_errors[field.attr('name')];
        if(!form_error){form_error='This field is required';}

        field.css({background:'#F8DBDB','border-color':'#E77776'}).after('<span class="error">'+form_error+'</span>');
    }

    window.onload=form_defaults;

});
</script>
</head>
<body>
<div align="center">
<div class="myform" style="padding:25px 0;">
<form action="/contact/" name="contact" onsubmit="return form_validate(this);" method="POST">
<div class="fb"><span class="finfo round">use this form for quick delivery of your message</span></div>
<div class="fb"><div class="lform round">Your Name:</div>
<input type="text" name="fullname" maxlength="100" size="35" class="inputtext" value=""></div>
<div class="fb"><div class="lform round">Contact Email:</div>
<input type="text" id="email" name="email" maxlength="100" size="35" class="inputtext" value=""></div>
<div class="fb"><div class="lform round">Message Subject:</div>
<input type="text" id="subj" name="subj" maxlength="100" size="55" class="inputtext" value=""></div>
<div class="fb"><div class="lform round">Your Message:</div>
<textarea id="msg" name="msg" cols="50" rows="6" class="inputtext"></textarea></div>
<span><input type="submit" name="submit" class="inputbutton mybutton round" value="Send Message" title="Submit Contact Form"></span>
</form>
<form action="/search.php" method="GET" name="search" onSubmit="return form_validate(this);">
    <input type="text" name="q" class="inputtext" value="" style="width:165px;"><input type="submit" class="inputbutton round" value="Search" title="Search">
</form>
<form action="/signup.php" method="GET" name="newsletter" onSubmit="return form_validate(this);">
    <input type="text" name="email" class="inputtext" value="test test asdfsdf" style="width:165px;"><input type="submit" class="inputbutton round" value="Register" title="Register Account">
</form>
<form action="/signup.php" method="GET" name="search2" onSubmit="return form_validate(this);">
    <input type="text" name="email2" class="inputtext" value="test test" style="width:165px;"><input type="submit" class="inputbutton round" value="Register" title="Register Account">
</form>

</div>
</body>
```

Thanks guys! Updated with working example.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

JQuery can select things by attribute e.g.

```
$("input[type='text']")
```

In your case however I think you'd need.

```
$(form.elements).filter("[type='text'], :not([type])"); //not([type]) included as browser defaults to text when attribute not present
```

I recommend having a thorough read through the [jQuery docs](http://api.jquery.com) - very well written, and you'll find the answers to a lot of jQuery questions there. How to select a particular element is covered by the selector and traversing sections.

Comment: I know I can do it that way, but I want to do it with the form variable which is passed from the onsubmit. On a couple pages I have more than one form, and wouldn't that return them all?

Comment: Edited to make it more relevant now

Answer (score 1):

Instead of

```
$(form.elements).each(function() { ...
```

Try just selecting the input elements with type=text

```
$("form input[type=text]").each(function() { ...
```

Answer (score 1):

If your `form` variable is a reference to the particular form you care about you can do this:

```
$('input[type="text"],input[type="password"]', form)
// or
$(form).find('input[type="text"],input[type="password"]')
```

The first uses the syntax `$('selector', context)`; the second simply selects the form first then finds elements within it. See the [jQuery ($) function doco](http://api.jquery.com/jquery/) for more details.

Or within your exiting `.each()` loop you can test `field.attr('type')` or just `this.type`.